# If Select tag option is selected shows another select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, select

I need code either in js or jquery or php like this.

```
<select id="1">
<option value="1">....</option>
<option value="2">....</option>
<option value="3">....</option> 
</select>
```

If option value 3 is selected, it should populate another select like

```
<select id="2">
-
-
</select>
```

if not value 3 is selected nothing happens.

Comment: What about if 1 is selected??

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. The header talks about _showing_ a select tag based on the selected option, the text talks about _populating_. Which one do you actually want to do? Or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by hiding and showing the other `select` depending on the value that is chosen (unless you want to populate the results dynamically after clicking option 3 in which case you will have to be more specific)

**HTML**

```
<select id="select1">
  <option>Choose One</option>
  <option value="1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="2">Val 2</option> 
  <option value="3">Val 3</option> 
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option>Choose Two</option>
  <option value="1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="3">Val 3</option> 
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
#select2{
   display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 3){
      $("#select2").show();
    }else{
      $("#select2").hide();
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4n5yv2d/)

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a PURE Javascript Solution

**See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/r6y5kb8z/)**

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("id1").value;
    if (x == "3") document.getElementById("id2").style.display = "block";
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="id1" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="id2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
#id2 {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

**Html**

```
<select id="1">
<option value="1">....</option>
<option value="2">....</option>
<option value="3">....</option> 
</select>

<select id="2" style="display:none;">
<option value="1">....</option>
<option value="2">....</option>
<option value="3">....</option> 
</select>
```

Your Jquery Here

```
$("#1").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 3){
      $("#2").show();
    }else{
      $("#2").hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<select id="1" class="first">
<option value="1">....</option>
<option value="2">....</option>
<option value="3">....</option> 
</select>

<select id="2" style="display:none;">
<option value="1">....</option>
<option value="2">....</option>
<option value="3">....</option> 
</select>

$(".first").change(function(){
var selectvalue=$(".first").val();
if(selectvalue==3)
{
$("#2").show();
} else {

$("#2").hide();
}

});
```